# Latex - placing limits under and above an integral (rather than near it)

Tags: syntax, latex, limit, integral

With the following syntax:

```
$ \int_{a}^{b} Foo dx $
```

I have the limits on the right of the integral sign.
I'd like to have them under and above.

Do I need a package for that?
Is there a way similar to

```
\lim\limits_{bla}
```

that doesn't require a recognized math operation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67053/putting-the-integration-bounds-below-above-the-integration-operator) is what you're looking for I believe.

Below the code snippet that places the integration limits under and above the integral sign.

`\[
    \int\limits_a^b f(x) \, \mathrm{d} x
\]`

[image: output]

Comment: Despite of the answer is pointing to a good ressource, pleave add some context to the link in your answer. Please compare the `Provide context for links` sections on the [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) site